# The shape of the button does not changes

Tags: android, android-layout

I found a way of changing shape on  previously answered questions
but after applying android:background="@drawable/x"
the attribute seems to be applied in layout preview but after debugging 
Sometimes normal background/no background appears.

Checked previous questions none were able to fix this.

drawable-> x.xml->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

layout->

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="95dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="228dp"
    android:background="@drawable/butt_shape"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

No error messages

Comment: The parent view of your drawable is `<selector>` which makes it a state list drawable. You should remove it. Look at the unownsp's answer for the right implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your background (name name.xml) something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="225"
        android:startColor="#DD2ECCFA"
        android:endColor="@color/loginBackground"/>

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topRightRadius="8dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="8dp"/>
</shape>
```

and in your button

```
android:background="@drawable/name"
```

Comment: It worked.Before code automatically created v24 drawable folder which led in error.

Comment: also whatif i want same color for the whole button?

Comment: do not use v24 drawable...use normal drawable....to create same color just keep startColor and endColor same in <gradient .../> tag above

Answer (score 0):

In your .xml

Put

`corner android:radius="25dp"`

In

Open and Close tag

Put all this in a shape tag.